# How do i make a discord bot reply to my command in a certain way

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have tried to write the conditional statement in various ways i found on the internet. But, the bot doesn’t seem to be recognizing my client id. What am I doing wrong?
Code:

```
  if(msg.author === '<@8421258276382****>')
{
        const yorepLKB = yoRepliesKB[Math.floor(Math.random() * yoRepliesKB.length)];
        msg.reply(yorepLKB);
}
```

Here, the id inside the quotations is my discord id.

Comment: Can you provide more information? Code samples/snippets, screenshots, errors, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`message#author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) returns a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) class, which does not equal `<@ID>`. (Though if you send a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) class in a [`message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message), Discord.JS will parse it as a mention.)

You can check the [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User)'s ID like this:

```js
if (msg.author.id === "123456789012345678")
{
   // Code
}
```